# How to prevent Android app installation if SDCard absent?

Tags: android

My code logic needs an SD card installed in the device. I have added a check for this case in the application's splash screen, but would like to inform users before they download/install this app. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this before the app installs, as the only way to limit such things is by using the [`<uses-feature>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) tag. However, that tag has no options for storage requirements. The best warning you can give is to prominently include it in your app description.

On the other hand, every device I've ever heard of an encountered has some form of external storage, be it a SD Card or inbuilt memory mounted as external storage. What you're doing by using the Splash Screen to check for the external storage is the best way to do this, as there is no other option.

Comment: It's good way. +1 
But my question is even if sd card is present and app is installed in the sd card, user can manually move the app to internal storage right?  I wonder if there a way to stop it.

Comment: Yes, the user can do that. There is no way to stop the user from moving the app to Internal Storage. However, if you want some data to stay exclusively on the SD Card, download/create it onto the SD Card the first time your app runs. That way, even if the user moves the app to internal storage, the data will remain on the external storage.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that. Your app have to be installed to be able to check user's environment. You could try to to enforce SD card installation of your app, so if there's none Google Play **might** (not tested) simply not allow app installation at all, but it will not solve your problem as user will still do not know why. Solution is to clearly state in product description that SD card is mandatory. But note, that requiring SD card is risky as many devices does not have any while still offer external storage. My suggestion - just add note about storage requirements and let system deal with it.

Comment: using preferExternal does not stop your app from being installed on the internal storage if the external one is short on space, or is not currently available.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is **NOT POSSIBLE** . **You are checking the sdcard on splash screen and prevent user for next process is the right solution** or Use `android:installLocation` for install android application on sdcard.

> Beginning with API Level 8, you can allow your application to be
>   installed on the external storage (for example, the device's SD card).
>   This is an optional feature you can declare for your application with
>   the android:installLocation manifest attribute.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    ... >
```

> If you declare "preferExternal", you request that your application be
>   installed on the external storage, but the system does not guarantee
>   that your application will be installed on the external storage. If
>   the external storage is full, the system will install it on the
>   internal storage. The user can also move your application between the
>   two locations.

**When your application is installed on the external storage:**

- There is no effect on the application performance so long as the
  external storage is mounted on the device.
- The .apk file is saved on the external storage, but all private user
  data, databases, optimized .dex files, and extracted native code are
  saved on the internal device memory.
- The unique container in which your application is stored is encrypted
  with a randomly generated key that can be decrypted only by the
  device that originally installed it. Thus, an application installed
  on an SD card works for only one device.
- The user can move your application to the internal storage through
  the system settings.

[Look Here for more details .](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html)